# Angular2 app components not rendering on full screen on WebOs LGTV

Tags: angular, angular2-template, webos, lg

I have an angular2 webos lg app which i am running on 32 inches. when am running this app , it showing black on half screen and component on other half

I have tried css to be make app compatible with 32 inches

I expect component render on full screen instead of half screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the app as FHD in the appinfo.json?

Webos apps are composed by the app (html5 + js + CSS files) and the metadata files (icons, background, etc)

The key metadata file is the appinfo.json which contains the resolution field. Please check that you are defining the app according your TV resolution (if the half of the screen is black maybe you have defined the resolution as 1280x720 in a 1920x1080 TV)